# iOS blured overlay view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

I want to have an custom iOS view which uses as a background, all views below the view blurred. In the view itself I don't know about the views. Can this be done and when yes how? thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

[`UIVisualEffectView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/) with the `UIBlurEffect` achieves exactly this. Your container will be an effect view, its content will be within its `contentView`.

As per [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBlurEffect):

> A `UIBlurEffect` object applies a blurring effect to the content layered behind a `UIVisualEffectView`.

So everything behind the effect view, found automatically by UIKit, will be blurred. Everything you've placed within the effect view, or which normal UIKit ordering puts above the whole view, will be on top of the blurred region.

Comment: its not possible with this because i want to have a custom view which when added to the view hirachy blurs as background all views below it

Comment: Your custom view could be a subclass of `UIVisualEffectView`. Or a view which contains a single `UIVisualEffectView` as its content. It will add the interesting subviews to its [/the visual effect view's] `contentView`. What makes this impossible for your use case?

Comment: i have multiple views which have to be blurred and they are dynamic, so the change their content and the can't be added as a subview to my overlay view

Comment: You don't add the views that you want to be blurred to the `contentView`.  All the views that are underneath the visual effect view are the ones that are blurred.

Comment: Yeah, my fault for giving such a short answer, possibly; appropriate documentation quote collected and inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you dont want to do it programmatically.

[image]